# Where can I find Ethereum raw transactions?

Tags: raw-transaction

For Bitcoin, I can use [this site](https://2coin.org/index.html) to find the hex encodings of raw Bitcoin transactions. Where can I find something similar for Ethereum?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use etherscan.io for this!

Look up an Ethereum transaction using the transaction ID. [Like this for txid=0xd1844c003fc2531625538800e2f7824b4913be73f34765472ad6fb547d0ce2df](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xd1844c003fc2531625538800e2f7824b4913be73f34765472ad6fb547d0ce2df).

Then find a button called "Tools & Utilities" in the top right corner of the box containing the transaction information. Use this button to choose "Get Raw TxHash". Then you will end up on a page [like this](https://etherscan.io/getRawTx?tx=0xd1844c003fc2531625538800e2f7824b4913be73f34765472ad6fb547d0ce2df) which reveals the hex encoded raw transaction.

In this example, the raw transaction is:

```
0xf86b808512a05f200082520894cf1838b517247ebdfd0e6db3c00d386e45bb808d8711c37937e080008026a01c0883e251dd34a0b1864618ac73483f8ece1b619d97525fabd821a111c2a7e9a018342cda6471ac519e9a5034fc65b644afa2a78bcff84c88b48185429376c7e4
```

Answer (score 0):

Infura has a developer API to return the raw data in JSON.

[Main Documentation](https://infura.docs.apiary.io/#)

To get the list of available methods:
https://api.infura.io/v1/jsonrpc/mainnet/methods

Example URL to get the JSON for one specific Tx: https://api.infura.io/v1/jsonrpc/mainnet/eth_getTransactionByHash?params=[%220xf97e9dcf0645e4686ec6ae8cecfe79bd945fe65bab12ec78c7d039916f8f3d81%22]

[Etherscan](https://etherscan.io/apis#transactions) also has a dev API, but you need to create an account and API key

Comment: This is helpful but I would prefer to be able to get the raw transaction in the encoding used on the Ethereum blockchain: The RLP encoding.

Comment: So you need more than just the `input` (data) portion which has the method signature and parameters? You want the entire `sendRawTransaction()` encoded message?

Comment: Yes. A hex string similar to this:
f889808609184e72a00082271094000000000000000000000000000000000000000080a47f74657374320000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006000571ca08a8bbf888cfa37bbf0bb965423625641fc956967b81d12e23709cead01446075a01ce999b56a8a88504be365442ea61239198e23d1fce7d00fcfc5cd3b44b7215f